# Shutting down Android phone from PC

Tags: shutdown

The screen of my Android phone sometimes automatically shutdown and cannot reshow again.

Can I shutdown my Android from PC or other ways?

Comment: For readers: betters answers are here: [How I shutdown Android phone with adb command?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/47989)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this with adb (Android Debug Bridge).

1. Enable "USB Debugging" on the phone (Settings > Applications > Development > USB Debugging)
2. Type `adb reboot` in a terminal in the directory where you installed adb platform-tools

Comment: Will it slow down the phone? if I enable the usb debugging in my phone.

Comment: @lovespring: USB debugging is only active when you plug the USB into a computer and adbd is active (i.e. you started adb in the computer), and in my Samsung Spica, there is no noticeable difference in my Linpack score when USB Debugging is "disabled" and "enabled while running Logcat" and "enabled but not running Logcat". YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

1. Hold the power button down until it shuts off.
2. Pull the battery out.

Comment: If I pull the battery out, the sdcard file system crashs, all file lost! This is why I ask this question.

Comment: That's not at all clear from your question.

Comment: @lovespring Notice the order of the steps here. They are very important, and if you follow them completely, you should be safe.

Comment: @Kevin The power button just shows a menu. from the menu I can select an item that shuts down the phone.

Comment: If you hold the button longer, it will initiate a shutdown.