# How can I shutdown my Android phone using an adb command?

Tags: adb, shutdown

How do I halt an android phone using adb command? I can reboot, but I don't know how to halt.

I tried `shutdown -k wait` command, but it did not work.

Answer (score 177):

Try `adb shell reboot -p` to shutdown the phone.

Comment: For those who wonder what the "p" stands for: it's short for `--poweroff` :)

Comment: it would have been better unix way: "shutdown" for shutdown and "shutdown -r" for reboot

Comment: Doesn't work for me though. Nexus 4 on Lollipop 5.0.1 (rooted), or LG P705 on ICS 4.0.3 (unrooted). I wonder if it's related to ADB version or not (mine's 1.0.32).

Comment: Try `adb reboot -p` (leave out `shell`).

Comment: reboot -p only reboots my tablet. Doesn't shutdown.

Comment: How did you find out? It's not mentioned in the official doc: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb

Comment: so strange on my lg g5 i have to do adb shell reboot -p. if i do adb reboot -p it just reboots and ignores the flag.

Comment: works fine on a nokia 6.1 running android 9 without root. at first glance I thought that it just rebooted because of the splash screen immediatly showing, but it was the "charging" mode that automatically booted up since the phone is plugged for adb.

Comment: Google Glass XE23 doesnt power off with the button as some docs indicate so I needed this to power off for storage. Thanks!

Comment: Seems to power off immediately, no graceful shutdown(?).

Comment: Does not work for my phone with AOSP rom on Android 10 unfortunately, seems to be model, adb version or Android Version related?

Answer (score 27):

**Note:** All the following commands below require root access.

On [Android Oreo](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/oreo-release/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml#3567), this works and *does a graceful shutdown*:

```
adb shell su -c 'am start -a com.android.internal.intent.action.REQUEST_SHUTDOWN'
adb shell su -c 'am start -n android/com.android.internal.app.ShutdownActivity'  #alternative; the aforesaid intent is supposed to be passed to this component under normal circumstances, but calling the component alone works too
adb shell su -c 'svc power shutdown'       # alternative; tested on Android 5.0, 6.0.1 and 8.1.0
```

Following is an alternative and is tested on Android 4.2, 5.0 and 6.0.1. I do not know about Nougat but it doesn't work for Oreo though.

```
adb shell su -c 'am start -a android.intent.action.ACTION_REQUEST_SHUTDOWN --ez KEY_CONFIRM true --activity-clear-task'   # I kept this here for historical purposes only.
```

### For low-level and instant shutdown

If you're running Android [KitKat](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.4_r1/services/java/com/android/server/power/PowerManagerService.java#2235) or above<sup><sup>*</sup></sup> and have root access, you can try this command:

```
adb shell su -c 'setprop sys.powerctl reboot,recovery'
```

- replace *su -c* with *adb shell* to run the command using [adb](/questions/tagged/adb)
- replace *reboot,recovery* with *reboot* to reboot the device
- replace *reboot,recovery* with *shutdown* to [shutdown](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.4_r1/services/java/com/android/server/power/PowerManagerService.java#2221) the device

---

<sup><sup>*</sup></sup> <sub>The last version on which the command is tested upon is stock Android 6.0.1.</sub>

Comment: "setprop sys.powerctl reboot,recovery" worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

here is an another method, go to android shell then shutdown the phone!

```
adb shell
shutdown
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work for me though. Nexus 4 on Lollipop 5.0.1 (rooted, even after using `su`), or LG P705 on ICS 4.0.3 (unrooted). I wonder if it's related to ADB version or not (mine's 1.0.32).

Comment: Doesn't work for me on an MIUI Redmi 3.  "shutdown: not found".

Comment: This is not a standard command

Answer (score 4):

In Windows Sub-system for Android(WSA) `shutdown` doesn't work instead try doing

`adb shell reboot -p` or

```
adb shell
reboot -p
```

[image: Shutdown Windows Sub-system for Android(WSA) via adb]

Answer (score 0):

To shutdown the phone use this command on PC:

```
adb shell halt
```

Comment: Doesn't work on stock 5.0 Galaxy S5 & 5.1 nexus 7,   Interestingly when run in CM12 `Reboot` process asked for superuser access and works in CM12

Answer (score -1):

Try

> adb shell "input keyevent 26"

It's work for me.

Comment: That would put the device to sleep mode or would awake it. 26 is [keyevent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent#KEYCODE_POWER) for power key. This cannot shutdown the phone.