# How to shutdown android via ssh command?

Tags: ssh

Is there any toolbox or app that will support issuing shutdown command via ssh to a rooted android smartphone? Note that I'm not asking [how to **restart** Android via command line (remotely)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/43706/16575) – but to really shut it down / turn it off.

Answer (score 3):

> reboot -p

was mentioned [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/47989/how-i-shutdown-android-phone-with-adb-command) which works for me on a rooted device. But someone mentioned [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/43708/31405) (see comments as well) that it's a bit harsh to simply shutdown without notice. So try something like this:

```
su -c 'am broadcast android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN && sleep 5 && reboot -p'
```

Comment: No issues known for turning off the device with `reboot -p`, then?

Comment: Works well here so far :)

Answer (score 1):

For me with an Android 4 device `reboot` doesn’t have a `-p` option, but there’s an alternative:

```
su -c "am start -a android.intent.action.ACTION_REQUEST_SHUTDOWN"
```

This is what’s used by Android as well, see [AndroidManifest.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.0.1_r1/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml#1582).

If you want to perform a more graceful shutdown broadcast `ACTION_SHUTDOWN` first, e.g.:

```
su -c "am broadcast android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN && sleep 5 && am start -a android.intent.action.ACTION_REQUEST_SHUTDOWN"
```