# `adb reboot -p` usually reboots instead of power-down which it is supposed to

Tags: adb, reboot

When writing:

```
adb reboot -p
```

I expect the unit to power down indefinitely. Instead, it just reboots automatically, the same as having written:

```
adb reboot
```

only.

Why is that? What should I write?

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/138057/96277

Comment: From my notes,  `adb shell reboot -p`.

Comment: shell only means it opens a shell first and writes the same there.

Comment: @JohnyTex Nein, it's not the same. `adb reboot -p` means *execute `adb` with arguments `reboot` and `-p`*. `adb shell reboot -p` means *execute a `shell` on the device, then execute the program `reboot` with argument `-p` which resides inside the device*. This is the difference.

Comment: Yes, what I meant (sloppily) was that the result is the same, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many phones start booting when a power cable is attached. This could be the reason here for the phone rebooting instantly instead of staying off.

Comment: Do know what could be done about that?

Comment: @JohnyTex you would have to disconnect your phone just after issuing the command

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
adb shell reboot -p
```

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. While this is a valid answer, could you [edit] and expand on the reason why it works? Otherwise, it's okay.